# ControlValueAccessor I am using deeply nested Custom Component, How to pass value from last Child-3 to the parent Component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder, controlvalueaccessor

I tried to mimic the folder structure as similar to my application.
Shared a stackBlitz link

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61duhd?file=src/app/child-1/child-1.component.html

Expected:
When printFormParent() clicked, I need to see the value of the input field from the child-3-a and child-3-b components.

How to pass the value of nested reactive forms?
What am i missing?

Comment: Did you try use the same parentForm and pass it throw each component,  and subscribe to changes?

Comment: @danywalls I didn't go with that approach, I wanted to use it with CVA. Attached is a stackblitz link as well. When you have time please have a check...